# BlackBerry application exits when there is an incoming phone call

Tags: blackberry

My BlackBerry application exits automatically when there is an incoming phone call. Is it possible to stop my application from exiting when there is an incoming call?

Comment: I didn't understand. What call?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, I think he's talking about getting an incoming **phone** call.  That's my guess.

Comment: @Nate exactly i need to prevent my application from getting exited when theres an mobile call

Comment: in normal case, your app will not exited.

Comment: As Signare says your application should not exit. There could be resource contention causing an exception that you aren't handling, or one of an unknowable number of other problems. Nothing anyone can do without some sort of crash analysis and the implicated source code, as Nilanchala says.